# Why can't I create a COM object in a new thread in Python?

Tags: python, com, comtypes, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a COM Object from a dll in a new thread in Python - so I can run a message pump in that thread:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
import threading

class MessageThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        print "Thread starting"
        connection = CreateObject("IDMessaging.IDMMFileConnection")
        print "connection created"

a = CreateObject("IDMessaging.IDMMFileConnection")
print "aConnection created"
t = MessageThread()
t.start()
```

this is the error trace I get:

```
aConnection created
Thread starting
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python26\lib\threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "fred.py", line 99, in run
    self.connection = CreateObject("IDMessaging.IDMMFileConnection")
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 235, in CreateObject
    obj = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(clsid, clsctx=clsctx, interface=interface)
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 1145, in CoCreateInstance
    _ole32.CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), punkouter, clsctx, byref(iid), byref(p))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 925, in GetResult
WindowsError: [Error -2147221008] CoInitialize has not been called
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You need to have called `CoInitialize()` (or `CoInitializeEx()`) on a thread before you can create COM objects on that thread.

```
from win32com.client.pythoncom import CoInitialize
CoInitialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember (long time ago I'e programmed a lot with COM Components) you have to call CoInitialize on each thread <strike>if your COM Object uses STA.</strike>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543(VS.85).aspx

But I've no idea how to call that function in python.

Here is the MSDN Doc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543(VS.85).aspx

Comment: You need CoInitializeEx() regardless of what the object uses.

Comment: many thx to the both of you... I've just done that and now I ole32.dll doesn't appear to return from CoCreateInstance. I'm trying to create the object before I start the message pump - is that ok?

Comment: Got it... d'oh... my COM DLL is implemented in VB6 and I had it set to STA rather than apartment threaded... all working now... have COM objects on a seperate thread sending messages to Excel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update with current experience using PyCharm and Python 2.7:
You need to import:

```
from pythoncom import CoInitializeEx
from pythoncom import CoUninitialize
```

then for running the thread:

```
def run(self):
    res = CoInitializeEx(0)
    #<your code>
    CoUninitialize()
```

PyCharm get confused with STA apartment, you need to enable true multithreading.

It is important that each `CoInitialize()` is terminated with a `CoUninitialize()`, so be sure your code follows this rule in case of errors, too.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer has said you need to run

```
CoInitialize()
```

However it is possible that the COMObject cannot just be passed to the threads directly. You will have to use `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()` and `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()` to pass instance between threads

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966218/18052428