# Using win32com with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, win32com

I am working on a web app with CherryPy that needs to access a few applications via COM.

Right now I create a new instance of the application with each request, which means each request waits 3 seconds for the application to start and 0.01 for the actual job.

I would like to start each COM application once and keep it alive and reuse it for a few seconds on the following requests because most of the time it is used by a burst of 5-10 ajax requests, then nothing for hours.

Is it possible to share a COM abject across all the threads of a CherryPy application?

Here is the summary of a few experiments that show how it is working now on each request and how it does not work across threads.

The following code successfully starts and stops Excel:

```
>>> import pythoncom, win32com.client
>>> def start():
    global xl
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

>>> def stop():
    global xl
    xl.quit()
    xl = None

>>> start()
>>> stop()
```

But the following code starts Excel and closes it after 3 seconds.

```
>>> import pythoncom, win32com.client, threading, time
>>> def start():
    global xl
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    time.sleep(3)

>>> threading.Thread(target=start).start()
```

I added the call to `CoInitialize()` otherwise the `xl` object would not work (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745617/win32com-client-dispatch-cherrypy-coinitialize-has-not-been-called/26753031#26753031)).

And I added the 3 second pause, so I could see on the task manager that the EXCEL.EXE process starts and is alive for 3 seconds.

Why does it die after the thread that started it ends?

I checked the documentation of [`CoInitialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx), but I couldn't understand if it is possible to get it to work in multithreaded environment.

Comment: The trick may be to initialize the thread for multithreaded apartment (aka, free-threaded) use. Try [CoInitializeEx](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/pythoncom__CoInitializeEx_meth.html) with the `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` option.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to use win32com in multiple threads you need to do a little bit of work more as `COMObject` cannot be passed to a thread directly. You need to use `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()` and `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()` to pass instance between threads:

```
import pythoncom, win32com.client, threading, time

def start():
    # Initialize
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
     
    # Get instance
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

    # Create id
    xl_id = pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch, xl)
 
    # Pass the id to the new thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, kwargs={'xl_id': xl_id})
    thread.start()

    # Wait for child to finish
    thread.join()

def run_in_thread(xl_id):
    # Initialize
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
     
    # Get instance from the id
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch(
            pythoncom.CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(xl_id, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
    )
    time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

For more info see: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-June/007788.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder why if there's a loop inside the thread the other threads are waiting. I have added a 'line' argument and was expecting same column cells in each n lines to change simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Mauriusz Jamro ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966218/7733418 ) was really helpful. Just to add to it, also ensure that you do:

```
pythoncom.CoUninitialize ()
```

in the end so that there's no memory leak. You can call it somewhere after using CoInitialize() and before your process ends.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: Building on an existing answer seems however OK to me....

Answer (score -3):

Try using multiprocessing. Worked for me, after a long search.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

p = Process(target=test, args=())
p.start()
p.join()
```