# Python COM Issues with OpenOPC when using a Threaded Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, com, opc, pythoncom

I am having an issue when trying to read OPC tags in a separate thread.
Currently using windows and connecting to the Matrikon OPC Simuator using the DCOM mode.
The code below works fine

```
opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation','localhost')
print(opc.read(['Random.Int1','Random.Int2','Random.Int4']))
```

However, when I attempt to read tags in a loop using a threading.Timer

```
def start():

    def readTags():
        # Start new threaded timer
        start()          

        # Read OPC tags. 
        print(opc.read(['Random.Int1','Random.Int2','Random.Int4']))

    # Create new threaded timer with the function to call after 1 second
    r = threading.Timer(1, readTags)
    r.start()

opc = OpenOPC.client()
opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation','localhost')
start()
```

I get the following error

> OPCError: AddGroup: CoInitialize has not been called.

I have a feeling this has something to do with sharing COM objects between different threads ([Using win32com with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading))
But cannot get it to work properly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Don't need `pythoncom` if all object is pyobject. Use shared class.

Comment: Thanks @dsgdfg, please could you elaborate on that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds 
check all errors and using the class. Otherwise the application will be garbage.  @rodp82

Comment: Thanks for your help @dsgdfg, but this does not solve my problem. This is  just another way (although, more elegant) of going about using timer threads. I am still getting the same error. My issue comes from the OPC COM object not being shared across threads