# why does this script not work with threading python

Tags: python, multithreading, win32com

so i've been trying to ifnd a way to access task manager.  I've tried a few methods including the wmi module and the windows tasklist but neither suit my need. wmi is way too slow and tasklist becomes too slow when i access it multiple times concurrently in something using multiprocessing.  so i found this script which works quite nicely but i can't get it to work with threading.

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
for objItem in colItems:
   print "Name: ", objItem.Name
   print "File location: ", objItem.ExecutablePath
```

this is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\python practice\stuff.py", line 5, in idk
    objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypiwin32-219-py2.7-win32.egg\win32com\cli
ent\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,c
lsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypiwin32-219-py2.7-win32.egg\win32com\cli
ent\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypiwin32-219-py2.7-win32.egg\win32com\cli
ent\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.II
D_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using win32com with multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading)

Answer (score 17):

You need to call `CoInitialize()` in order to use `win32com.client`:

```
import pythoncom
import win32com.client as client

pythoncom.CoInitialize()

strComputer = "."
objWMIService = client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

for objItem in colItems:
    print "Name: ", objItem.Name
    print "File location: ", objItem.ExecutablePath
```

For more background information see [using win32com with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966218/6341291)

Comment: This has saved me. Thank you so much!