# Word access denied with win32 python

Tags: python, django

I use Python 3.6 and Django 1.11.
I created a Word document with MailMerge and it was ok. 
Right now I need to save this document as a pdf document.

```
import win32com.client as win32
from os import path
word = win32.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
filedoc='c:\\growthtech\\Capturar6.docx'
filepdf='c:\\growthtech\\Capturar6.pdf'
in_file = path.abspath(filedoc)
out_file = path.abspath(filepdf)
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file, 'rb')
doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat=17)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

It occurred the error bellow in line "doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file, 'rb')".

```
>>> doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file, 'rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Tipo não correspondente.', None, 2)
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Something wrong with arguments of `doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file, 'rb')`... Is `'rb'` really needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from os import path
word = win32.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
in_file = path.abspath('c:\\growthtech\\Capturar6.docx')
out_file = path.abspath('c:\\growthtech\\Capturar6.pdf')
# just one argument here
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
# was: 'new_file'
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=17)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly in python shell mode, but when I included in my code, it occurred the error : "(-2147221008, 'CoInitialize não foi chamado.', None, None)"

Comment: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize is not called.', None, None)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258257/why-does-this-script-not-work-with-threading-python ?

Comment: Congratulations! )