# Pickle cython class in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have a class that is implemented in cython containing c-pointers which I'm trying to use together with python's multiprocessing module. The class takes a DLL-file to return an instance of the class.

The problem I have is that while the instances preserve their data type, they seem to be empty, i.e. I can access all their class functions but they've lost all their instance values I set before they entered. The code containing special_class is very big so I'm not able to include it.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from special_module import special_class

def run_task(tasks,nr):
    obj = tasks[nr]['data']
    print obj.get_name()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    m1 = special_class("a.dll")
    m2 = special_class("b.dll")


    tasks = dict()

    tasks[1] = {'data': m1}
    tasks[2] = {'data': m2}


    process1 = mp.Process(target = run_task, name = 'process1', args = (tasks, 1))
    process2 = mp.Process(target = run_task, name = 'process2', args = (tasks, 2))

    process1.start()

    time.sleep(0.2)

    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

Above script gives me the output

```
None
None
```

The correct output should be in the style of

```
name.a
name.b
```

If I create the instances inside the function run_task it will work fine, but I'm looking for a way to make it work by creating the instances in the main process. Is this possible?

Comment: Try [using a custom pickler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html).

Comment: Every windows(OS) `class access` required a registered point on Python. You access a DLL but how to set all `data access` procedure. Need using `pythoncom.CoInitialize()`. [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading)

Comment: Umm... `import special_class` followed by `m1 = special_class("a.dll")` isn't legal; you can't call a module. I assume it's slightly different in the real code, but either way, the Cython class definition is important here; you can't omit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiprocessing library works by pickling objects and then piping the data to other spawned processes. The issue is that your `special_class` is unpicklable.

> If I create the instances inside the function run_task it will work fine

This works because then the object does not need to be pickled, which works around the issue.

---

You need to make your `special_class` picklable. This can be done in various ways. They are all documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-inst

Basically, there are 3 mechanisms:

- Use a custom pickler
- Implement a `__reduce__` method on `special_class`
- Implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods on `special_class` (if your class instances have states)

I have a feeling that you have a reference to an external object in your `special_class`. In that case, refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#persistence-of-external-objects

Answer (score 2):

I believe multiprocessing.Process pickles all its arguments. So you need to tell Python how to pickle special_class. You just need to implement method special_class.__reduce__ so that the data can be pickled properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are making `m1` and `m2` both the full `special_class` *module*. If you are trying to make them a certain *class*, either do:

```
from special_class import *
```

(which I recommend) or

```
m1 = special_class.special_class("a.dll")
m2 = special_class.special_class("b.dll")
```

The `None` is probably appearing because the methods you input `m1` and `m2` into also accept the module, for some reason. I would suggest trying `from special_class import *` and work it out.

Comment: No, the `None` appears because it's not able to pickle the object. If I dont use the multiprocessing module I dont get this problem.