# Error with win32com.client.GetObject when connecting to SAP GUI

Tags: win32com, sap-gui, pythoncom, moniker

Dears,
first of all this is the first time I ask a question on Stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm not following the right way to do this.

I kindly ask for your help as I'm facing an issue with win32com.
I'm trying to connect to SAP GUI in order to automate certain tasks.

```
import win32com.client

SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
```

I get the following error (until yesterday everything was working fine..):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/PySAPscript.py", line 157, in <module>
    SAP_OP()
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/PySAPscript.py", line 18, in SAP_OP
    SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\PycharmProjects\yyyyyy\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 72, in GetObject
    return Moniker(Pathname, clsctx)    
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\PycharmProjects\yyyyyyy\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 87, in Moniker
    moniker, i, bindCtx = pythoncom.MkParseDisplayName(Pathname)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221020, 'Invalid syntax.', None, None)
```

I've found some documentation about this issue which suggests using pythoncom.CoInitialize():

[Using win32com with multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764978/using-win32com-with-multithreading)

However I can't figure out how to use this function for my purpose.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem recently.

The startup permissions of sap and python are not the same.
For example, both of these should be run with administrator rights, or run with ordinary user rights.

I do not guarantee that this method will solve your problem, but you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering, that you have variables (SAP_Path, SAP_system_id, SAP_group) or (SAP_Path,
SAP_sid, SAP_instance_no) instead...

```
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")


call(SAP_Path + " /R/" + SAP_system_id + "/G/" + SAP_group)
OR: call(SAP_Path + " " + SAP_sid + " " + SAP_instance_no)

    
sap_gui_obj = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
application = sap_gui_obj.GetScriptingEngine
connection = application.children(application.connections.count - 1)
session = connection.children(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()
```

Then connect to your base.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run SAP GUI Script triggered from Flask (desktop) application. Solution that works for me is to embrace the code operating with SAP GUI with `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` and `pythoncom.CoUinitialize()` statements:

```
def display_document():
    import win32com.client
    import pythoncom

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    sap_gui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
    sap_app = sap_gui.GetScriptingEngine
    sap_conn = sap_app.Children(0)
    sap_session = sap_conn.Children(0)
    sap_session.StartTransaction("FB03")

    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```