# How can I set value on slider

Tags: python-3.x, com, pywinauto, uia

I tried set value on slider. I can connect to it. But then I try set value catch `_ctypes.COMError: (-2146233079, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))`
[I tried this, but it not helps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246525/why-cant-i-create-a-com-object-in-a-new-thread-in-python)

Comment: can you give a full exaple of your code.

Comment: [Here it is](https://pastebin.com/eFMd5ZSj)

Comment: Usually this error means that ValuePattern has incorrect implementation on app side. Which patterns are supported for this slider in Inspect.exe?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, [this is copyclipboard](https://pastebin.com/gA2Dfxnj) from Inspect.exe

Comment: Thanks! This is RangeValuePattern. Let me some time to provide a workaround when I’ll be near PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... This is interesting. We have working unit tests for standard WPF slider. See [test_uiawrapper.py, line 780](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/unittests/test_uiawrapper.py#L780) for reference.

Everything looks the same in Inspect.exe also. But for WpfApplication1.exe it works.

[EDIT] **Wait! You pass int number** to `set_value(...)`, how about `float` or `str`?

P.S. I can suggest a workaround since you should have "thumb" control as a child of the slider: `slider.children(control_type="Thumb")[0]`. You can play with rectangles of the slider and the thumb (`.rectangle().mid_point()`), then use `click_input(coords=(x, y), absolute=False)` with relative coordinates calculated for specified value. Or even `.drag_mouse_input(...)` is better, because one click should call just a small move in the direction of click.

Comment: yes, I tried to pass float and string to set_value(...). I had same results.
"I can suggest a workaround since you should have "thumb" control as a child of the slider..."
I thought about this decision, but I decided to wait for the answer. Looks like I'll have to do so. Thanks!